# Adding Javascript or importing js file into Angular 9 component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular and creating a project that that uses routing. I'd like to import a js file from src/assets/js/custom.js

I've created a service that imports an injectable like so

test.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class TestService {
    testFunction() {
      console.log('Test');
    }
}
```

home.compontents.ts looks like

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { TestService } from './test.service';

declare var require: any

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'],
  providers: [TestService]

})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {private testService: TestService}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.testService.testFunction();

  }

}
```

But I am getting the following error

```
17   constructor() {private testService: TestService}
                    ~~~~~~~
src/app/home/home.component.ts:19:13 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

19   ngOnInit(): void {
               ~
src/app/home/home.component.ts:20:9 - error TS1005: ':' expected.

20     this.testService.testFunction();
           ~
src/app/home/home.component.ts:20:36 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

20     this.testService.testFunction();
                                      ~
src/app/home/home.component.ts:24:1 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

24 }
   ~
```

I've tried so many different ways from Google searches and not coming up with anything.
Can anyone please help?

UPDATE

Thanks for the updates, I've updated the constructor, however I am getting an error

```
ERROR in src/app/home/home.component.ts:3:29 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './test.service' or its corresponding type declarations.

3 import { TestService } from './test.service';
```

I'm not sure if I am going the right way with this. Each component I am using has 1 or 2 js files that I need to import. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Correct way -  constructor(private testService: TestService) {}

Comment: Before asking these types of question you should at least google once and get ans on the fly.

Answer (score 3):

A service passed as a parameter in class constructor to be injected as a dependency.

```js
constructor(private testService: TestService) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

The constructor is written incorrectly. Please write it as given below

```
 constructor(private testService: TestService) {}
```

Also, you have given service as `@Injectable()`,then you have to define the service in `app.module.ts` file.
Alternatively, you can give

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

This will eliminate adding the service in providers.

Comment: Ahh thank you! Although it's still not quite right
```
ERROR in ./src/app/home/home.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './test.service' in 'root/angular-electron/src/app/home'
    ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts:53:2 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Injectable'.
    53 @Injectable({ src/app/home/home.component.ts:3:29 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './test.service' or its corresponding type declarations.
    3 import { TestService } from './test.service';
```
My full app.components looks like this
https://gist.github.com/paddywinc/96e1fa3fb0f2ff9bfdaa5ebeb8787ea6

Comment: in your app.module.ts , 
    '@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root'}) ' After removing, it should work.

this is not required. The test service should be annotated with that. But as you are adding the provider in the component, so , you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

home.compontents.ts constructor should be like below:

```
constructor(private testService: TestService) {}
```